# Evil keybindings in reftex-toc

Tags: key-bindings, evil, reftex-mode

I would like to bind `j` to `reftex-toc-next` and `k` to `reftex-toc-previous` whilst in a reftex-toc buffer. According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/reftex/reftex_56.html), the keymap active in `*toc*` buffers is `reftex-toc-map`. I'm using `use-package` to load reftex, so I've tried

```
(use-package reftex
  :ensure t
  :after (latex)
  :bind (:map reftex-toc-map
              ("j" . reftex-toc-next)
              ("k" . reftex-toc-previous))
  :config
  (add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-reftex)
  (setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t))
```

Which produces the following error

```
Error (use-package): reftex/:catch: Symbol's value as variable is void: reftex-toc-map
```

Any suggestions as to why this doesn't work and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 3):

I faced this exact problem and solved it by using evil-collection just on refTeX. Installed it as an additional package in my `dotspacemacs/layers()`

```
(setq-default
  ...
  dotspacemacs-addtional-packages
  '(...
    evil-collection
    ...)
 ...
 )
```

And initialised it only for refTeX in my `user-config()` through

```
(evil-collection-init 'reftex)
```